# Translate yii2 based website

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a website using Yii2 . And I am new also in Yii2. I have read the translation options of Yii2 here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html . It seemed a bit complex to me and I didn't understand  what really to do well.
So what about copy the project to a subdomain and just replace the words with its translations? Or should I learn Yii2 translation option and use it?

Any advice is very important me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you not understand? It's very bad practice to copy project and replace words. Yii2 translations are very very easy, just try them.

Comment: You should learn deeply the Yii2 translation features ..

Comment: So I should Yii2 translation features rather than copy the project? But it seems easy to copy the project rather than using Yii2 translation features.

Comment: No, it's not easy, try add one feature with 5 languages project. You have to change 5 times one thing.

Comment: So I think all of you are  right. I have to learn Yii2 translation feature deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function for translations: 
`<?=Yii::t('app','Text to translate')?>` 
and in MyProject/messages/en/app.php

`return [
    'Text to translate' => 'Translated text',
    'Other Text to translate' => 'Other Translated text',
  ];`

you need to define in web.php default language

```
'language'=>'en'
```

and in web.php components array

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```